# Is it possible to add ssh-key to AWS EB for accessing npm private deps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My application has some private dependencies(repos at gitlab), normally I use ssh keys for installing them with npm.

Can I do the same with AS EB? Add ssh-key so when I do "eb deploy" it can download and update all private modules? Or maybe there is another better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do all of the build process outside of EB so that all you are deploying to EB is the packaged code with everything it needs.

If you are just building locally and deploying you can cover this off yourself.

Alternatively use a tool like Codeship or similar to handle your builds and deployments to EB, You can add SSH keys to Codeship to be used to access private dependencies..

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you just commit node_modules folder into the git repo?

Comment: No not into the git repo. The CI/CD approach through codeship, builds everything i.e. install node modules does some gulp tasks etc... then packages up a zip file which is pushed to S3. This contains everything that is needed and EB deploys from this zip file.